# Using dplyr to average time series groups with individuals of different lengths

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, time-series, line-plot

Consider `dat` created here:

```r
set.seed(123)
ID = factor(letters[seq(6)])
time = c(100, 102, 120, 105, 109, 130)
dat <- data.frame(ID = rep(ID,time), Time = sequence(time))
dat$group <- rep(c("GroupA","GroupB"), c(322,344))

dat$values <- sample(100, nrow(dat), TRUE)
```

We have time series data for 6 individuals (6 `ID`s), which belong to 2 groups (`GroupA` and `GroupB`). We want to make a line plot that shows the "average" time series of both groups (so there will be two lines). Since the individuals all have different lengths, we need to do `dat%>%group_by(group)`, and shave off values after the shortest `ID` within both groups. In other words, `ID == a` is the shortest in group 1, so the "average" line for `GroupA` will only be 100 values long on the x-axis; likewise `ID == d` is the shortest for `GroupB` so the "average" time series of `GroupB` will be 105 values long on the x axis (`time`).
How can we do this (preferably through a `dplyr` pipe) and send the data to `ggplot()`?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for rolling window averages. Have you considered checking out [`slider`](https://github.com/DavisVaughan/slider) package or using `rollapply` from [`zoo`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/zoo/versions/1.8-8/topics/rollapply) to accomplish?

Comment: @akrun thanks I understood where you were going, your answer was helpful as well. That was my bad for missing the line that created the response variable when I copied it over

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(maxtime = max(Time)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(maxtime = min(maxtime)) %>%
  group_by(group, Time) %>%
  summarize(values = mean(values)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Time, values, colour = group)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, I missed a line when copying this over from R. I added your values to the question so that you don't have to modify your answer.

Comment: Thanks @Ryan. I'll remove the header on my answer

Comment: It is not clear why this is different from `dat %>% group_by(group, Time) %>% summarize(values = mean(values))`. May be you need a `slice` instead of `mutate` after the `group_by(group)`

Comment: @akrun it just allows the ends to be trimmed off so that any Times that do not have the complete set of IDs are not represented. I think `dat %>% group_by(group, Time) %>% summarize(values = mean(values))` would keep the values within each group after the shortest ID had completed, which the OP didn't want.

Answer (score 2):

We could do

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
   add_count(group, ID) %>%
   group_by(group) %>%
   mutate(n = min(n)) %>%
   group_by(group, ID) %>% 
   summarise(values = mean(values[seq_len(first(n))]))
```